# Deleting WMI instance with C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com, wmi

I have found some samples with C# and VBS for WMI instance deletion, however I need this implemented with C++.

My sample code:

```
CoInitialize(NULL);

HRESULT hRes;

//Obtain the initial locator to WMI
CComPtr<IWbemLocator> pLoc = NULL;
hRes = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID*) &pLoc);
if(FAILED(hRes))
    return 1;

//Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method
CComPtr<IWbemServices> pSvc = NULL;
//Connect to the root namespace with the current user and obtain pointer pSvc to make IWbemServices calls.
hRes = pLoc->ConnectServer(L"ROOT\\SUBSCRIPTION", NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, 0, &pSvc);
if(FAILED(hRes))
    return 1;

hRes = pSvc->DeleteInstance(
           L"CommandLineEventConsumer.Name='{709782F3-E860-488E-BD8A-89FBC8C1495C}'",
           WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, NULL, NULL);

return 0;
```

According to that I've found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392101%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), my code should work. I surely have `CommandLineEventConsumer` named `{709782F3-E860-488E-BD8A-89FBC8C1495C}` [image]

And my code fails on `IWbemServices::DeleteInstance`, error code `0x80041008` (One of the parameters to the call is not correct).

I would appreciate if someone spot mistake in my code. Or maybe some privileges are required to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found two solutions:

1.Remove `WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY` flag.

```
_bstr_t objPath(L"CommandLineEventConsumer.Name='{709782F3-E860-488E-BD8A-89FBC8C1495C}'");
hRes = pSvc->DeleteInstance(objPath, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

2.Pass `IWbemCallResult` for result.

```
_bstr_t objPath(L"CommandLineEventConsumer.Name='{709782F3-E860-488E-BD8A-89FBC8C1495C}'");
CComPtr<IWbemCallResult> pRes = NULL;
hRes = pSvc->DeleteInstance(objPath, WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, NULL, &pRes);
```

Didn't investigate a lot, but it works both ways. Looks like specs aren't 100% correct.

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter to [IWbemServices::DeleteInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392101.aspx) is a `BSTR`. A `BSTR` is different from a UTF-16 encoded C-style string in that it stores an explicit length argument. Even though `BSTR` is of type `wchar_t*`, you cannot pass a plain string literal in place of a `BSTR`.

To create a `BSTR` from a string literal you need to call [SysAllocString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221458.aspx):

```
BSTR objPath = ::SysAllocString(L"CommandLineEventConsumer.Name='{709782F3-E860-488E-BD8A-89FBC8C1495C}'");
hRes = pSvc->DeleteInstance(
       objPath,
       WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, NULL, NULL);
::SysFreeString(objPath);
```

Alternatively, since you are already using ATL for `CComPtr` you could use [CComBSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh7x9w3f.aspx) to make your life easier:

```
CComBSTR objPath(L"CommandLineEventConsumer.Name='{709782F3-E860-488E-BD8A-89FBC8C1495C}'");
hRes = pSvc->DeleteInstance(
       objPath,
       WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, NULL, NULL);
```

---

Note: [IWbemLocator::ConnectServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa391769.aspx) also needs `BSTR`s as parameters. The sample provided on the documentation page does pass a plain C-style string, so maybe the `IWbemLocator` interface is more forgiving when presented invalid parameters.

Comment: It doesn't work neither with `BSTR` nor `CComBSTR`. Also `BSTR` is typedefed as `OLECHAR*`, `OLECHAR` as `WCHAR`, `WCHAR` as `wchar_t`. So basically `BSTR` and `wchar_t*` are the same.

Comment: @ST3: `BSTR` and `wchar_t*` are the same **type** in C or C++, but with fundamentally different semantics. A [BSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069.aspx) is a composite data type that consists of a length prefix, a data string, and a terminator. As a counted string it can contain embedded NUL characters. A C-style string, on the other hand, is zero-terminated, and thus cannot contain NUL characters, since it doesn't maintain an explicit length prefix. What error code are you getting when using a real `BSTR`?